# Counting the number of values per column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume the following `table`

```
---------------------------------------------
ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4  ...  ColN
--------------------------------------------
1             bla     foo                abc
2     foo     abc
3     bar
4                     baz
5     baz     bar     cuz
6                     123                foo
7     123
8                     oof
--------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to list to count the number of values per column without having to make a separate query for each column?

So output would be like:

```
----------
Col   Hits
----------
Col1  4
Col2  3
Col3  5
Col4  0
...
ColN  2
----------
```

Any push into the right direction would be great!

Comment: What is a "value", i.e. if `foo` appears twice in a single column is that one value or two? Are the _other_ values `NULL` and does that count as one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot and aggregate:

```
select v.which, count(v.col)
from t cross apply
     (values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), . . . ('coln', coln)
     ) v(which, col)
group by v.which;
```